# Navigation Drawer above Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

I implemented a navigation drawer on my android app and works fine. But my problem now was, my menus in my nav drawer became lengthy where the bottom menu was under my nav bar. How do I bring my navigation drawer on top of the nav bar?
Both Lollipop and Marshmallow have the same behavior.

Please find below snip.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_song_list_main" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: But isn't your NavigationView's list scrollable? I tested on the Navigation Drawer template from Android Studio, and it seems that when the list is long, it becomes scrollable and you have to scroll it in order to see the latest elements.

Comment: @Laura

It is scrollable and the last menu was the "settings" as shown in the above snip. When you scroll, it end up there in the settings and under the nav bar.

Comment: Maybe it's a theme issue. Does your app or activity theme have these 2 attributes: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>. You can also take a look on this tutorial http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2016/07/13/android-navigation-view-tabs/. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the NavigationView outside the DrawerLayout, and put these both within the LinearLayout having orientation="vertical"

```
<LinearLayout... orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its not working and I received error regarding no drawer in left something like that.